# Smallest number of a hypothetical second Collatz Cycle

Tags: recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

**Update/warning:** The explaination below contains some obvious errors.
These errors have been worked on and turned this research into: [Generating (almost?) all odd numbers for the 3n + 1 problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833252/generating-almost-all-odd-numbers-for-the-3n-1-problem)

Most here are probably aware of the Collatz Conjecture. It is conjectured that every number eventually ends in a trivial cycle of 1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 if you follow these rules:

Take any number:

1. If it is odd, multiply by three and add one
2. If it is even, divide by two
3. Repeat.

First of all, a disclaimer: I'm not a mathematician, I'm a computer programmer that likes math (a lot) and it trying to learn more. Maybe the thing I'm doing here is *very* wrong or trivial, just tell me. This is what I want to find out/learn... I hope some of you will follow along and teach me new things.

**Smallest number in the cycle**

If a second cycle in the Collatz Conjecture exists, it must have a smallest number in the cycle. This number has some interesting properties (if it exists).

Lets call the smallest number of the cycle Y.

First of all:

```
Y % 2 = 1
```

Y can't be even because that would divide by two creating a smaller number.

This leaves Y to be either:

```
Y = 6*n + 1
Y = 6*n + 3
Y = 6*n + 5
```

**Preceding numbers**

Let's look at the numbers preceding Y:

`Y = 6*n + 3` is impossible. The number before this step in the cycle must be `Y * 2`. Thus `X = Y * 2 = 6 * ((n * 2) + 1)`, `X%6=0`. There is no odd number that can form such a number `X%6=0` because `(odd * 3) + 1` is always `X%6=4`. So this number can't be part of a cycle.

`Y = 6*n + 5` is also impossible. The number before this step in the cycle must be `Y * 2`. Thus `X = Y * 2 = 6 * ((n*2) + 1) + 4`. This number is `X%6=4`, but there is an odd number W that comes before X in the cycle:

```
W = ((X)-1)/3
W = ((6 * ((n*2) + 1) + 4)-1)/3
W = 4*n + 3

And we know:
Y = 6*n + 5
```

As you can see `W < Y`. Thus Y isn't the lowest number in the cycle, preceding number W is smaller. Y in this form can't be the lowest point of a cycle.

This leaves `Y = 6*n + 1` as only option.

**Looking forward**

Next we can look at the numbers after Y:

Because Y has the form `6*n + 1` we know something about the next two numbers in the sequence.

```
Y = 6*n + 1
Z = Y*3+1 = 18*n + 4
A = Z / 2 = 9*n + 2
```

Next I want to split Y into two groups, with n being even and n being odd:

```
Y = 12*i + 1
A = 18*i + 2
```

And:

```
Y = 6 + 12*j + 1
A = 9 + 18*j + 2
```

The first form `12*i + 1` can be proven to be false, except for i=0 (the trivial known cycle 1>4>2>1)

When i = 0:

```
    Y = 1
    A = 2
    Now A is even and there is a successor B, which is A/2:
    B = A/2 = 2/2 = 1. This is equal to Y and can make the trivial loop. But this breaks Y > 1.
```

When i > 0:

```
    Y = 12*i + 1
    A = 18*i + 2
    B = 9*i + 1

    Given i>0 the resulting B is smaller than Y, thus Y isn't the lowest number, resulting number B is smaller.
```

So this leaves `Y = 6 + 12*j + 1` as the only possible form for a smallest number in an hypothetical second cycle?

This eliminates 91.6% of the numbers, maybe there is a trick to eliminate the remaining 8.4%? Or am I doing something very weird here, making mistakes etc?

Comment: Hmm, I've at the moment not the brain to follow you, maybe I can come back to this later today or tomorrow. Perhaps you are interested in an earlier discussion of mine where I however have looked only on the odd numbers of a possible cycle, but also looked at modular properties of consecutive numbers in such a cycle (for instance residues $\pm 1 \pmod 6$ ) In case you're interested: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf for instance sec 2.3 pg 6 and then ff

Comment: (... contd...) Of course that the smallest element $Y$ of a cycle must be odd and also of the form $Y_\text{odd} = 4n+3$ has been observed often elsewhere. But for the preceding (odd) numbers there is no restriction known other than they are in the same form $6j \pm1$ as all members of the cycle, and $Y$ must share both descriptions: $Y=4n+3 = 6k \pm1$ and its odd precedessor must have the form $X_{\text{odd}} = 4n+1  = 6j  \pm1 $

Answer (score 0):

Define the function $f(x)=4x+1$

If we analyse where any odd number $n$ receives branches from the odds which precede it, firstly $n\equiv0$ mod $3$ receive no branches, obviously.

$n\equiv1$ mod $3$ receive branches on their even powers of $2$ - given by $f^q(\frac{4n-1}{3}):q\in\mathbb{N}$, and

$n\equiv2$ mod $3$ receive branches on their odd powers of $2$, given by $f^q(\frac{2n-1}{3}):q\in\mathbb{N}$

The only case in which one odd rises to the next, is if it lands on the lowest odd power of $2$, i.e. if:

$n_m=(3n_{m-1}+1)/2$

And you are right, in what I think is the 2nd part of your question these numbers whose successors are greater, are in a minority.  The first example is the number $3$.

However coming to the first part of your question, this is not correct because every number $n$ has an immediately preceding number which is greater.  If we take the number $31$ for example, which is on the well-known long string which leads from $27$ to $1$, we see that it rises afterwards but there are many numbers **immediately** preceding it which fall to it, which can be obtained by the formula I described above:

$f^q(\frac{4n-1}{3}):q\in\mathbb{N}=\{41,165,661,2645,10581,\ldots\}$

Even if some immediate predecessor of $q$ was lower than it, there are other immediate predecessors to it which are above it and some loop could come via any one of those.

Answer (score 0):

My frank suggestion is that to learn mathematics it is more profitable to play with simple number theory rather than wasting time on open problems like the Collatz conjectures.

> Y = 6*n + 3 is impossible. The number before this step in the cycle must be Y * 2. Thus X = Y * 2 = 6 * ((n * 2) + 1), X%6=0. There is no odd number that can form such a number X%6=0 because (odd * 3) + 1 is always X%6=4. So this number can't be part of a cycle.

This very first step is wrong.

Here is a counter-example sequence:

$6n+3\,,12n+6\,,24n+12\,,\cdots$

You assumed incorrectly that a doubling step must be preceded by a triple-plus-one step. However, despite your wrong proof, it is in fact true that a cycle cannot have the least member being a multiple of $3$, since it must be before a larger number and hence when we can trace backwards and there must be a triple-plus-one step somewhere, but after repeated doubling a multiple of $3$ remains a multiple of $3$ and can never be the result of a triple-plus-one step.

> Y = 6*n + 5 is also impossible. The number before this step in the cycle must be Y * 2. Thus X = Y * 2 = 6 * ((n*2) + 1) + 4. This number is X%6=4, but there is an odd number W that comes before X in the cycle [...]

Same error again. Counter-example: $6n+5\,,12n+10\,,24n+20\,,48n+40\,,16n+13\,,\cdots$.

I stopped reading at that point, because this approach is doomed to fail.

Comment: "This very first step is wrong." You're wrong here. The OP is talking about odd predecessors, and no multiple of $3$ has an odd predecessor, as he says, since no number of the form $2^nx:x\equiv 0$ mod $3$ is in the range of $f(x)=3x+1$.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Did you even read my post? I stated exactly what you stated as true. However the asker stated a **false** claim regarding the immediate predecessor. You need to read more carefully before making judgements.

Comment: He's talking about an element of a hypothetical loop, which would require an odd predecessor.  He also includes "There is no odd number that can form such a number" as part of his reasoning. I think it is you who has been quick to criticise.

Comment: @RobertFrost: Sorry but you're simply mistaken. As I said before, your lack of understanding of logic is making you unable to recognize logical errors. He claimed that: "**The number before this step** in the cycle must be Y * 2 = 6 * ((n * 2) + 1), X%6=0. There is no odd number that can form **such a number X** because (odd * 3) + 1 is always X%6=4." (slightly edited to fix syntactically invalid bits) This is **logically invalid**.

Comment: While precision is important in maths, and it may be helpful to address that, I think it's important to interpret the OP's intentions and to address the question they *intend* to ask, rather than some technicality.

Comment: @RobertFrost: If he had only made that error in that case of "6n+3", it can be argued that it is just a slip of language. However, he made **EXACTLY THE SAME ERROR** in the other case, which is the place of the CRUCIAL FLAW. So I'm calling a duck a duck. Enough of this.

Comment: All he did, was mention later the condition that he is requiring a number which has an odd predecessor, rather than stating it up front. I think if you had made a sincere attempt to interpret his intentions you would have realised this.

Comment: I made a sincere attempt, and have pointed out to the asker the logical error. I was not talking to you and shall stop talking to you about this since you're not willing to give up your pride.

Comment: @user21820, If fact, he is correct, because a hypothetical loop, cannot contain a multiple of three. The most obvious proof of this is that the step $3x+1$ can never result in $0 mod 3$, thereby never closing the loop. And there is really no need to get quite so defensive/aggressive. Also accusing people of having a "lack of understanding of logic" is really quite impolite, especially since you most likely have no idea who you may be talking to.

Comment: @roskiller: Your mathematical comment is correct, but what I stated in my post is also correct, because the asker gave a **logically incorrect** proof. Also, it seems you didn't even read the rest of my post, which conclusively shows that the asker **really made that logical error**. As for RF, I stand by what I said, and the moderators and the logic experts on this site know very well about him. If you don't know his history, don't comment. Your claim that I most likely have no idea whom I may be talking to is **so ironically false**.

Comment: "My frank suggestion is that to learn mathematics it is more profitable to play with simple number theory rather than wasting time on open problems like the Collatz conjectures."

I can only speak for myself, but I was motivated to study "simple number theory", up to a Ph.D. dissertation about algebraic fields, originally because I was bitten by the Collatz bug. It has inspired the development, in me, of tools and perspectives that have allowed me to discover things I would not have seen otherwise. I wouldn't presume to second-guess someone else's inspiration.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: As I stated, it was **frank** and a **suggestion**. You have no evidence that you would not have been motivated by other things to get pretty much to where you are now even if the Collatz conjecture never existed. I'm not presuming to know that you would, but I'm merely saying that your experience provides hardly any evidence that my frank suggestion was bad. It is difficult to analyze the importance of factors influencing any person's life, even our own.

Comment: @user21820, I have not claimed that your suggestion was bad. I have stated an alternative perspective, for the benefit of readers, and I have said how *I* view the situation. I am happy for this site, where we can both share our perspectives. I wish you all the best in your studies and your life; may inspiration visit you frequently and profitably :)

Comment: @GTonyJacobs: Ah okay sorry I misunderstood your intended meaning. Thanks for clarifying! All the best to you too! =)