# Generating (almost?) all odd numbers for the 3n + 1 problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics, collatz-conjecture

## The 3n + 1 problem

The $3n + 1$ problem can be described as a set of simple rules. For any positive integer apply the following two rules:

- If the number is even: divide by 2
- If the number is odd: multiply by 3 and add 1

Here is an example:

`7 -> 22 -> 11 -> 34 -> 17 -> 52 -> 26 -> 13 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 ...`

### Collatz conjecture

One thing to notice in the example above is that the pattern ends in a `1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1` cycle. Collatz has conjectured this will always happen, for each positive starting integer.

### Proving/disproving Collatz

To prove or disprove this conjecture someone will need to:

1. Find a counter example: a number grows forever or another cycle.
2. Prove that a cycle can't exist.
3. Prove that all odd numbers can be generated by other numbers working backwards.

People have been using super computers to crunch numbers to find a counter example to the Collatz conjecture. As of 2020 people have checked up to $2^{68}$, and all examples end up in the same `1 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1` cycle.

We could state that, for a second cycle to exist, there has to be some specific properties of the numbers *inside* the cycle. For example, every cycle has **one** lowest number in it; and for any repeating cycle it can't have $6n + 3$ numbers in it (more on that later).

This lowest number in a cycle might have some very specific properties that only $1$ has, thus making a second cycle impossible.

### Generating numbers (working backwards)

A final way to *prove* the Collatz conjecture is to show that all other numbers can be created by starting at $1$.

Lets take a closer look at all the numbers involved.

Even numbers can easily be ignored, they will (in a cycle) always get divided down to an odd number. Because every even number is an odd number multiplied by a power of two.

For example $80$ comes down to `80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5`. Because of this we can just focus on the odd numbers in the $3n + 1$ problem.

#### Splitting the odd numbers

The numbers that we need to focus on are:
$$2n + 1$$

These are all the odd numbers. Let's split these numbers into three equal groups:

$$a = 6n + 1$$
$$b = 6n + 3$$
$$c = 6n + 5$$

We can show that these groups all uniquely contain the odd numbers:

$$a [1, 7,  13, 19, 27...]$$
$$b [3, 9,  15, 21, 29...]$$
$$c [5, 11, 17, 23, 31...]$$

Going a single "Collatz" step back from an odd number means multiplying by 2, this creates new even numbers:

$$a_1 = 12n + 2$$
$$b_1 = 12n + 6$$
$$c_1 = 12n + 10$$

$a_1 - 1$ and $b_1 - 1$ are not divisible by three and have no odd predecessor at this depth.
$c_1 - 1$ **is** divisible by three and it creates a pattern: $4n + 3$

This implies that from every number in the form $6n + 5$, going one step back in the Collatz sequence, we can generate all $4n + 3$ formed numbers.

When multiplying $a_1$, $b_1$ and $c_1$ again by two (going a deeper step back) we get:

$$a_2 = 24n + 4$$
$$b_2 = 24n + 12$$
$$c_2 = 24n + 20$$

$b_2 - 1$ and $c_2 - 1$ are not divisible by three thus have no odd predecessor at this depth.
$a_2 - 1$ **is** divisible, and reveals pattern: $8n + 1$

### Special case: 6n + 3

Because `b` is in the form $6n + 3$, multiplying by two will never result in a number that minus one is divisible by three. This means that odd numbers of form $6n + 3$ have no odd numbers preceding them.

This allows us to focus completely on $6n + 1$ and $6n + 5$ form numbers.

### Pattern equations

For `a` and `c` we can come up with the following equations:

$$a = \frac{2^{2k} (6n + 1) - 1}{3}$$
$$c = \frac{2^{2 k + 1} (6 n + 5) - 1}{3}$$

Depth $k$ determines how deep we travel backwards (multiplying by two).
The values for $k$ from the equations are:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
    k & a & c \\ \hline
    1 & 8n + 1 & 4n + 3 \\ \hline
    2 & 32n + 5 & 16n + 13 \\ \hline
    3 & 128n + 21 & 64n + 53 \\ \hline
    4 & 512n + 85 & 256n + 213 \\ \hline
    5 & ... & ... \\ \hline
\end{array}

All the odd numbers that could be in a repeating cycle now have a method to calculate all their preceding odd numbers at different depths of $k$.

At a depth of $k=1$ we get the following information as mentioned above:
$6n + 1$ and $6n + 5$ numbers will generate patterns:
$8n + 1$ and $4n + 3$

This means all numbers in the forms: $8n + 1$, $8n + 3$ and $8n + 7$ can be generated.
After $k=1$ we just miss the numbers in the form $8n + 5$.

Next we look at $k=2$, the new additions are: $32n + 5$ and $16n + 13$. Scaling everything to $32n$ we can see that we can now form all odd numbers except in the form $32n + 21$.

One level deeper again and the patterns added are: $128n + 21$ and $64n + 53$. This means that we can now form all odd numbers except those in the form $128n + 85$.

If this process is repeated, we can see that all odd numbers can be generated starting from just $6n + 1$ and $6n + 5$.

#### Density

The amount of odd numbers that can be calculated are:

$$\frac{4^k-1}{4^k}$$

The largest number that, at depth $k$, can't yet be created is equal to:

$$ 2 \cdot 4^{k+1}n + \frac{4^{k+2}-1}{3}$$
This results in the following table for small values of $k$:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
        k & Missing & Density & Percentage \\ \hline
        1 & 8n + 5 & \frac{3}{4} & 0.75 \\ \hline
        2 & 32n + 21 & \frac{15}{16} & 0.9375 \\ \hline
        3 & 128n + 85 & \frac{63}{64} & 0.984375 \\ \hline
        4 & 512n + 341 & \frac{255}{256} & 0.99609375 \\ \hline
        5 & 2048n + 1365 & \frac{1023}{1024} & 0.9990234375 \\ \hline
        6 & 2 \cdot 4^6n + 5461 & \frac{4095}{4096} & 0.9997.. \\ \hline
        7 & 2 \cdot 4^7n + 21845 & \frac{16383}{16384} & 0.99993.. \\ \hline
        8 & 2 \cdot 4^8n + 87381 & \frac{65535}{65536} & 0.99998.. \\ \hline
        9 & 2 \cdot 4^9n + 349.525 & \frac{262143}{262144} & 0.999996.. \\ \hline
        10 & 2 \cdot 4^{10} n + 1398101 & \frac{1048575}{1048576} & 0.99999904... \\ \hline
        .. &  &  &  \\ \hline
        100 & 2 \cdot 4^{100} n + 214..... &  & 0.9999999999... \\ \hline
         & 2 \cdot 4^{k+1}n + \frac{4^{k+2}-1}{3} & \frac{4^k-1}{4^k} &  \\ \hline
\end{array}

After just $k=10$ steps we can generate $\frac{1048575}{1048576}$ of all existing odd numbers from the starting values $6n + 1$ and $6n + 5$. The lowest number we can't create is $2 \cdot 4^{10}n + 1398101$.

And after $k=100$ steps we're up to:
$$0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999993777$$

**Update**:

#### Does this "prove" the Collatz conjecture?

Sadly: No.

There is one problem: We did show that each odd number can be made from $6n+1$ and $6n+5$. We **haven't** shown that this all happens from the number 1.

**Update 2**:

Suppose a second cycle exists. That cycle will have to have a lowest number, that is larger than 1 (obviously).

Can we prove this cycle doesn't exist? We can try.

First of all, we can still rule out any numbers in the form $6n+3$, these numbers have no preceding odd numbers and can therefor never be created in a cycle.

Now we have two options left, $6n+1$ (`a`) or $6n+5$ (`c`).

Let's look at the numbers in `c`. They are in the form $6n+5$, and have smaller predecessors in the form $4n+3$. These are the only numbers that can make a cycle grow exist and odd numbers grow larger when running Collatz forward:

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
        n & 4n + 3 \\ \hline
        0 & 6 \cdot 0 + 3 \\ \hline
        1 & 6 \cdot 1 + 1 \\ \hline
        2 & 6 \cdot 1 + 5 \\ \hline
        3 & 6 \cdot 2 + 3 \\ \hline
        4 & 6 \cdot 3 + 1 \\ \hline
        5 & 6 \cdot 3 + 5 \\ \hline
        6 & 6 \cdot 4 + 3 \\ \hline
        7 & 6 \cdot 5 + 1 \\ \hline
        8 & 6 \cdot 5 + 5 \\ \hline
        9 & 6 \cdot 6 + 3 \\ \hline
        10 & 6 \cdot 7 + 1 \\ \hline
        11 & 6 \cdot 7 + 5 \\ \hline
\end{array}

From this we can conclude that we either:

1. The smaller odd number before $4n+3$ is a smaller $6n+1$
2. The smaller odd number before $4n+3$ has the form $6n+3$, a dead end
3. The smaller odd number before $4n+3$ is a smaller $6n+5$, continue until (1) or (2) are reached (will happen by deduction).

This means that the only possible smallest odd number in a cycle can be in the form $6n+1$, a number from group `a`.

Suppose we again split `a` into two groups `a1` and `a2`:

$$a1 = 12n + 1$$
$$a2 = 12n + 7$$

These groups contain all $6n+1$ numbers, split equally.

If we now follow the sequence forward from our hypothetical lowest number in the cycle we get:

$$((12n + 1) * 3)+1 = 36n + 4$$
$$((12n + 7) * 3)+1 = 36n + 22$$

Next we divide the even numbers by two (according to the $3n+1$ rule) and get:
$$(36n + 4)/2/2 = 9n + 1$$
$$(36n + 22)/2 = 18n + 11$$

This shows that a number in form `a1` ($12n + 1$) is not the lowest number of the hypothetical Collatz cycle because $9n + 1$ follows and is smaller.

So the lowest number in an hypothetical cycle must be $12n + 7$.

**What next?**

One could dive deeper into these $4n+3$ numbers; those are very special and allow a number to grow before going down to 1.

One could try to come up with a set of finite sub-trees that create the fractal like pattern the $3n+1$ problem has?

I'm giving up (for now) :)

Comment: I do not understand the table. Does it mean that the counterexamples must have, for example, the form $2048n+1365$ ? If this were the case and could be extended to larger powers of $2$, the search limit should be much larger than $2^{68}$.

Comment: There are several heuristics indicating the truth of the collatz conjecture, and apparently almost all mathematicians consider it to be true. But even overwhelming heuristics cannot replace a proof. Goldbach's conjecture as well as the twin prime conjecture "cannot be false" , but surprises cannot be ruled out, see Goodstein-sequences.

Comment: There’s a non-zero probability that the Goldbach conjecture is false according to our knowledge, except that probability is ridiculously close to zero. And if I had a 100 digit counter example, we wouldn’t be able to prove it’s a counter example. Twin prime conjecture is false with probability zero according to heuristics. Probability zero ≠ impossible.

Comment: Equivalent to the Collatz conjecture is: for every n >= 2, the Collatz sequence starting with n has an element less than n. That’s much easier and faster to prove for many n.

Comment: I think it does mean that we only need to check that higher number, and the bounds can indeed be much bigger. More importantly: I think the boundary might could be pushed to infinity, meaning proving the conjecture... equations a and c combine to make a perfect set of all odd numbers going deeper.

Comment: What you describe is well known (e.g. http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?43,1505780,1510790#msg-1510790). You can't talk about coverage by going backward from $6n+1$ or $6n+5$ since you don't even know if it is (already) part of a cycle or a divergent trajectory. But you are "almost" right: Here is a post about the density of those numbers (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527924/what-fraction-of-all-mathbbn-are-powers-of-2/2528069#2528069)

Comment: @Collag3n I've updated the 'question' to reflect what you've mentioned. Indeed it doesn't "prove" Collatz because we can't be certain that we reach all $6n+1$ and $6n+5$. It does show that each odd number is generated uniquely and hints towards having ordered groups in a directed graph.

Comment: The directed graph is a tree in the positive natural numbers; its known (odd) root is a single number. But in the negative numbers it is known, that at least 3 trees with distinct roots reside -so to say- "intertwined" : one tree with root $-1$, one tree with root which is a loop of two odd numbers ($-5,-7$), and a third root which is a loop of 7 odd numbers, I think containing the value $-17$. We must understand how (and why) it is possible for multiple infinite trees to coexist "intertwined" (in the negative numbers) but not in the positive numbers. Here we should make deeper progress...

Comment: ... Sometimes I speculate whether we have a problem comparable with the 4-colour-problem which has been resolved after finding (with help of computer-power) 4097 (?) specific patterns which cover the whole problem-space. Perhaps we can catalogize patterns of finite subtrees, which fit together like pieces of a puzzle...

Comment: Btw. +1 for the nice presentation! (Perhaps you like to see my early thoughts on this, pretty parallel to your ideas: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf )

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Indeed, with such a predictable way to build parts of the tree. There is also a weird trick in the modulo 6 of the generated odd numbers. For example $8n+1$ makes 1,3,5..., $32n+5$ makes 5,1,3... $128n+21$ makes 3,5,1... (this repeats for list a. $4n+3$ makes 3,1,5... $16n+13$ makes 1,5,3,... and finally $256n+213$ makes 5,3,1... so we have all distinct combinations (repeating).

Comment: This feels like the start of two interleaved predictable fractal patterns; there has to be a specific rule that directs each odd number.

Comment: There exist different kinds of graphs and trees that I think is analogous to the types you're talking about. For example for $3n+2^t$ where $t$ is highest power of two that divides $n$ or something like this, generates different sets, its unclear to me which one of these alternatives can be ruled out or wether its possible to find a solution to all of them.

Comment: The "probability" that Collatz is true is not comparable with the "probability" that Goldbach or the twin-prime conjecture is true. The "chance" that Collatz is false is MUCH higher.

Comment: @RoyvanRijn - What is your question?